# Checking if elements of an array are included in elements of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, string-matching

I'm trying to match 2 arrays and check if all elements of the first array are included in the second one.

My first array looks like this and it contains a series of selected ingredients

```
selectedOptions:  Array [
  "egg",
  "spaghetti",
  "cream",
]
```

the second array contains the recipe of a dish and looks like this

```
"ingredients": Array [
    "spaghetti",
    "raw egg",
    "double cream",
    "tomato sauce",
]
```

Now, I have a function that iterates through an array of objects and each object contains the "ingredients" array

here is the code

```
const availableRecipes = recipeList.filter(function (item, i) {
      if (
        selectedOptions.some((option) =>
          item.ingredients.includes(option)          
        )        
      ) {
        return true;
      } else false;
    });
```

this function works fine, in the sense that it loops through my recipe array and checks for each item if the "egg" and "spaghetti" are part of each recipe.

**THE PROBLEM**

The function only returns True if the recipe contains exactly the entire word i.e. "egg" or "cream".
In my example recipe it will return False as it doesn't contain "egg" but "raw egg" and "double cream" instead of "cream".

I think the problem is with using ***includes*** in `item.ingredients.includes(option)`

Is there anyway that I can do a partial match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another `.some`, to iterate over each string to see if the substring is included:

```
const availableRecipes = recipeList.filter((item) => {
  return selectedOptions.some(
    option => item.ingredients.some(
      ingredient => ingredient.includes(option)          
    )
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For consistency, you'll also need to `return false;` after your final `else`, rather than just stating `else false;`

Comment: Thanks for spotting it!