# Need help to use array.some() to check if existing cities in arrays are included in array of phrases

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

I have a list of cities and I have a list of phrases. I need to check if the cities exist in the phrases and based on this return "big city" or "not a big city"

I thought it would be simple with the some() function but I seem to be not clear about how it really works. I've tried with with a single string for a city and an array of cities.. but both don't seem to work..

I have check this question ([Checking if elements of an array are included in elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64378726/checking-if-elements-of-an-array-are-included-in-elements-of-another-array)) and maybe the answer is there but there seems to be a use of filter there.. do I have to do that or can I not just use some and get the result?

I'd appreciate some help with some explanation why the below code does not work.. I've lost one day trying to figure it out but I can't seem to.. In my head the `result` should be 'big city' twice in the code below .. once for 'new york' and once for 'milan'

```
// COMMON FOR BOTH

const phrases = ['I live in San Francisco','I live in milan in italy', 'I live in Los Angeles', 'I live in New York City']


// WITH AN ARRAY

const cities=['paris',"new york",'milan'];

function checkCities(phrase){
  
  cities.forEach(city=> phrase.includes(city));

};
                       
const result1 = phrases.some(checkCities) ? "big city" : "not a big city";


console.log('result1',result1); // Output "not a big city"


// WITH JUST A STRING

const city = 'new york';

const result2 = phrases.some(checkCity) ? "big city" : "not a big city";

console.log('result2',result2); // Output "not a big city

function checkCity(phrase){
  
  phrase.includes(city);

};
```

Comment: When you say _"I need to check if the cities exist in the phrases"_ do you want to check that all of the strings in `cities` exist in at least one of the strings in `phrases` or do you want to check that at least one city string from the `cities` array is in a string from the `phrases` array?

Comment: Sorry if was not clear.. i'll try and update the question.. but I want to check if, in any of the phrases, if any of the cities exist then return a "a big city".. at least that's what I was trying to achieve with my code.. as I assumed that `some()` returns true if any of the condition returns true.. am I right?.. I am still trying to figure it out in my head how `some()` works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with your misunderstanding of how the function you pass to `.some()` should work. The function you pass to `.some()` will be called by JS multiple times, once for each element in the array that you called the `.some()` method on - in your case, that is each string in the `phrases` array. The function should also *return* a `true` or `false` value (or a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value). When you return `true` from your function, the `.some()` method stops any further iterations and returns `true` (indicating you've met the condition you're trying to check), if you return `false`, the `.some()` method will continue its loop and check the next element in your array. If the function passed to `.some()` doesn't return `true` for any value in your array, then the `.some()` method returns `false` after checking all items in your array. You can read abut the details of the `.some()` method on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

In your code, the function you're passing to `.some()`, `checkCities`, does not `return` anything from it, so it automatically returns a value of `undefined` every time JS calls it, which to the `.some()` method is the same as returning `false` for each element.

As you outlined, you want to "check if, in any (`.some()`) of the phrases, if any (`.some()`) of the cities exist then return a *"a big city"*". We can try and turn this sentence into code (see code comments below):

```js
const phrases = ['I live in San Francisco','I live in milan in italy', 'I live in Los Angeles', 'I live in New York City'];
const cities = ['paris',"new york",'milan'];

// If "any"--------------v   of the phrases...                   
const result1 = phrases.some(checkCities) ? "big city" : "not a big city";

function checkCities(phrase){
  // If "any"---v of the cities "exist"------------v
  return cities.some(city => phrase.toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase()));
  //                      ^--- arrow function without body `{}`, so the return value is implicit
};

console.log('result1', result1); // Output "not a big city"
```

Here we're using two `.some()` methods, one on the outer `phrases` to iterate through each `phrase`, and the an inner `.some()` to check if any of the `city` strings are in the current `phrase`. If the inner `.some()` method returns `true` (indicating that a `city` has been found in a `phrase`), then your outer `.some()` method will also return `true`, otherwise, if the inner `.some()` method is unable to find a city in any phrase, then it will return `false` for each `phrase` that is iterated on by the outer loop, which will result in your outer `.some()` method returning `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
...
// WITH JUST A STRING
...
function checkCity(phrase){
  if (phrase.toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase())) return phrase
};
```

WITH AN ARRAY: you can loop for each city with "JUST STRING" code

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion : As `includes` is a case sensitive. Hence, `'new york'.includes('New York')` will return `false`. You can either convert both the strings in `lowerCase()` to check if it exist or not.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const phrases = ['I live in San Francisco','I live in milan in italy', 'I live in Los Angeles', 'I live in New York City'];

const city = 'new york';

function checkCities(city) {
  return phrases.some((phrase) => phrase.toLowerCase().indexOf(city.toLowerCase()) > -1);
}

console.log(checkCities(city) ? "big city" : "not a big city");
```

**Note :** Above code will work perfectly if you want to search for a single city at a time.